# Дизайнер ругается на EventSetter

Tags: wpf, xaml

Вот кусочек кода.

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="OnTabHeaderMouseMove"/>
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OnTabHeaderLeftButtonDown"/>
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="OnTabHeaderLeftButtonUp"/>
</Style>
```

Все работает замечательно, но вот в дизайнере `Handler="OnTabHeaderLeftButtonUp"` и остальные хандлеры подчеркнуты синим. При наведении вижу тултип с текстом

> Недопустимое значение для свойства "Handler": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.XmlValue"

Это происходит каждый раз при использовании `EventSetter`. Проблем это не создает. Еще раз говорю, все работает замечательно, но подчеркивания напрягают и сбивают с толку. Может, студия как то криво настроена?